# Systemd service start cannot find command in starter script

Tags: shell-script, systemd

I have a program that I want to run as a daemon, let's call it dummy. I have to parse params for it, so I need a starter script, a config file and the program itself as well as it's dependencies, these are in the same folder, let's say in `/usr/share/dummy`. Every program, script...etc is 0755.

*(Yes I know this is far from perfect, normally the program will be in `bin`, dependencies in `lib`, config in `etc` or somewhere else, this is just a proof of concept daemon test.)*

---

Service file for program:

```
[Unit]
Description=Dummy daemon program
After=default.target

[Service]
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/share/dummy/dummyd_start.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

My starter script (more or less):

```
#!/bin/bash

#Some config parsing...

sudo ./dummy $PARAM
```

*I cannot call the program itself from the service file because at the moment I need to process parameters for it, also the program needs root privilages.*

If I just run the starter script from its location (`sudo ./dummy_start.sh`) it works fine, starts the program. But if `systemd` starts it, it doesn't find the program itself:

```
Mar 10 16:42:52 debian systemd[1]: Started Dummy daemon program.
Mar 10 16:42:52 debian bash[10690]: sudo: ./dummy: command not found
Mar 10 16:42:52 debian systemd[1]: dummy.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 10 16:42:52 debian systemd[1]: dummy.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

It doesn't matter if I change the service file call like `ExecStart=/bin/bash -c /usr/share/dummy/dummyd_start.sh`. If I call the program in the starter script by the full absolute path (so in the starter script it's like `sudo ./usr/share/dummy/dummy $PARAM`), it can find the program...but not its dependencies:

```
Mar 10 16:26:23 debian systemd[1]: Started Dummy daemon program.
Mar 10 16:26:23 debian sudo[10420]:     root : PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=./usr/share/dummy/dummy -p some_parameters
Mar 10 16:26:23 debian sudo[10420]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Mar 10 16:26:23 debian bash[10421]: ./usr/share/dummy/dummy: error while loading shared libraries: libmysqlclient.so.21: cannot open shared >
Mar 10 16:26:23 debian sudo[10420]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Mar 10 16:26:23 debian systemd[1]: dummy.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Mar 10 16:26:23 debian systemd[1]: dummy.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Anyone any idea what am I missing?

Comment: I think I may found the solution in the meantime: if it helps anyone, here's what I missed.

It doesn't matter if the start script is in the same folder as the program, the systemd still thinks the program is in the folder of I don't know, the service file. Anyway, the solution is to `cd` into the correct folder in the starter script...

Comment: it also makes no sense to use `sudo` to start the script as root; just run the service as root.

Comment: When you're trying to start anything with systemd, you need to include EVERYTHING it needs. All the paths, all the environment variables, everything. If you dig, you can find the wrecks of all who failed (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/739328/systemd-service-start-cannot-find-command-in-starter-script)...Just because the user who is supposed to run the script has that information in their environment, you CANNOT assume that systemd will load and run that. Everything MUST BE EXPLICIT.

Answer (score 1):

The code `./dummy $PARAM` wants to find `dummy` in the current directory, whatever this is at the moment the script executes this line. It is a common misunderstanding that this might refer to the directory of the calling script.

I guess you manually start your script like `cd /usr/share/dummy; ./dummyd_start.sh` or by clicking it in a file manager which does it in a similar way.

If your code relies on a specific current working directory you have to use `cd`.

Another option would be to determine the location of the running script and prepend this to all called scripts.